# Spring MVC 3: Is there any tag similar to h:outputText of JSF?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-form

I am not able to find a tag for displaying dynamic text bound to a bean. i.e. similar to **h:outputText** as given in JSF.
We have form:input, but nothing which can display the bean property in a text form.
Is there any such tag in Spring? If not, is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

> **18.4.5 Bind support and form handling**
>   Spring provides a tag library for use in JSP's that contains (amongst
>   other things) a  tag. This tag primarily enables forms
>   to display values from form backing objects and to show the results of
>   failed validations from a Validator in the web or business tier. From
>   version 1.1, Spring now has support for the same functionality in both
>   Velocity and FreeMarker, with additional convenience macros for
>   generating form input elements themselves.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html